# Why do I get java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem when I execute my main via a Process in another class but not when I run it by itself?

Tags: java, process, compiler-errors, processbuilder, distributed-system

I'm using Java, developing in Eclipse a student project wherein I need to build a simple distributed system. I decided to model this on one computer through multiple Processes, however I appear to be doing something wrong.

So I have a class Test, wherein I am attempting to use a ProcessBuilder to make and execute three Processes running the main of another class Player. When I run the main of Player (with 3 arguments) by itself, it appears to run fine (though it doesn't progress because it expects 2 other players), but when I try to run it through Test I just get the following output:

```
Working dir: C:\Users\Jeremy Canning\git\cs-3700\cs-3700
Enter number of games to play: 
10
[java, -cp, bin, Player, 228.5.6.7, 6789, 10]
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at Player.main(Player.java:164)
at Player.main(Player.java:164)
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at Player.main(Player.java:164)
```

Each process is giving the same error: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at Player.main(Player.java:164)`
Since this error only occurs when I run it through `Test.main` it seems that the compilation problem lies within that method. I imagine I may be improperly building my Processes, but I have not been able to diagnose what I'm doing wrong with any certainty in my own research. If anyone can spot my error in `Test.main` you would be doing me a great boon.

```
public class Test {
    public static String programName = "/cs-3700/src/rockPaperScissors/Player.java";
    public static String arg0 = "228.5.6.7";
    public static String arg1 = "6789";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println("Working dir: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of games to play: ");
    String arg2 = String.valueOf(kb.nextInt());
    String[] exec_cmd = {"java", "-cp", "bin", "Player", arg0, arg1, arg2};

    try {
        String[] cmd = {"javac.exe", "Player.java"};
        ProcessBuilder compile = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        compile.directory(new File(workingDir));
        //System.out.println(compile.directory().getAbsolutePath());
        Process p = compile.start();
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(exec_cmd);
        pb.directory(new File(workingDir));
        pb.inheritIO();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pb.command().toArray()));
        //System.out.println(pb.directory().getAbsolutePath());
        Process[] players = {pb.start(), pb.start(), pb.start()};
        for(Process player : players) {
            player.waitFor();
        }
        }catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    kb.close();
}
}
```

EDIT: I'm going to add my code for the main method of the Player class here for reference. The first line of it (the declaration of main) is the Line 164 referred to in the Error given above.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // Line 164
    if(args.length == 3){
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int numGames = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        Player player = null;
        try {
            InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            player = new Player(group, port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.multipleGames(numGames);
    }else{System.out.println("No arguments");}
}
```

Comment: Which is line 164? Why are you trying to compile your code from the program? Wouldn't you expect a player to start his own program, rather than you trying to do so centrally?

Comment: Class files produced by javac never throw "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem" (javac doesn't create class files if there are compilation problems). These errors can be thrown if the source code is compiled by the eclipse java compiler. My suggestion: execute "javac Player.java" from a command prompt, it should show you the problem in the console output

Comment: @daniu Line 164 is the declaration of the main method of Player. In any practical application yes I would expect a player to start his own program which would connect with other players but in my test case which I'm trying to get to work I need to test that my network programming is functional, which I'm trying to do by starting Processes running Player.main. My compilation mid program may no longer be necessary but I added it as a response to seeing it as something that worked for someone with a related issue.